# Unable to get_attribute('src') from iframe tag in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, getattribute

I have the following HTML code:

```
...
<div class="media ipad_media" style="padding-top: 0;">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="618" height="330" data-gtm-yt-inspected-7182449_30="true"> 
    </iframe>
<div>
...
<div class="media ipad_media hidden-xs">
   <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="618" height="330" data-gtm-yt-inspected-7182449_30="true">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

I want the `src` attribute which is actually the same in both `iframes`. I just locate the first element by using the following command:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("media.ipad_media").find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

I then excute the following:

```
print(elem.get_attribute('width'))
print(elem.get_attribute('frameborder'))
print(elem.get_attribute('allowfullscreen'))
print(elem.get_attribute('src'))
print(elem.get_attribute('source'))
print(elem.text)
print(elem.tag_name)
```

I get the following in the console:

```
618
0
true

None

iframe
```

How is it possible to get nothing executing `print(elem.get_attribute('src'))`? As you understand, executing the `$$("div.media.ipad_media>iframe")` command in the console gives `2`

Comment: What locator are you using to locate the IFRAME? Please add that to your question. My guess is that the page has more than one IFRAME and you didn't end up with the one you were looking for.

Comment: Also: the src could be dynamically loaded on the page and you could be fetching it before it's populated.

Comment: @JeffC I have edited the description accordingly

Comment: @DMart I have put it to sleep for 5s before printing the src

Comment: `"media.ipad_media"` is not a class name. It's actually two class names (which won't work in `find_element_by_class_name()`) but you've mixed in some CSS selector syntax (the `.` between the two class names). I would suggest that you change the chained `find_element()` calls to just `elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.media.ipad_media>iframe")`.

Comment: @JeffC I have changed the locator but I get exactly the same outcome.

Comment: Update your question with the current code you are using. Are there any other IFRAMEs on the page? Have you tried running `$$("div.media.ipad_media>iframe")` in the dev console and confirm that only 1 element is found?

Comment: @JeffC There are actually 2 iframes. I have edited the description accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The `<div>` tag is the immediate ancestor of the desired `<iframe>` tag.

To print the value of the `src` attribute of the `<iframe>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.media.ipad_media > iframe").get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='media ipad_media']/iframe").get_attribute("src"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.media.ipad_media > iframe"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='media ipad_media']/iframe"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```